# Regex: Combining negative and positive expression on sentences

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler

Cheers everybody,

I'm writing a web crawler in python. Since I have faced certain problems using beautiful soup I am digging deeper into regular expressions.

My problem set is the following: Let's say my text looks like this:

```
<title>Document</title>
<head>test and whatever</head>
<body style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;">test and not whatever.</body>
<body style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;">test and not whatever. 
This is a text after the dot. And this is a text after the dot but with test in it. 
And a text with test and not.</body>
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is to extract the sentences in which the string "test" appears, but not to extract the sentences in which the string "not" appears as well.

A sentence can either start with a "." or ">" and end with a "." or "<".

I have already figured out how to extract the sentences with "test" in it. Namely by using the regex code ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2S7dNG/1)):

```
[^\>|.]*test[^\<|.]*
```

Unfortunately sentences in which "not" appears as well are being extracted too. So, what I would like the output to look like is:

```
test and whatever
And this is a text after the dot but with test in it
```

I have tried

```
[^\>|.]*(?=test)((?!not).)[^\<|.]*
```

which is unfortunately not working. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks and best regards, Gerrit

Comment: (1) I suggest you figure out how to fix your problems with BeautifulSoup. (2) You don't need to do everything using regex, you can just find sentences containing `test` and then use simple python to remove those that contain `not`.

Comment: Hey Alex, beautiful soup is unfortunately no opportunity anymore. First getting all sentences with 'test' in it and then removing those with 'not' in it will probably lead to more computing time? I actually hoped that this line of regex isn't a big deal

Comment: Complex regexes are slow. If you get an answer you can measure the performance, I'm guessing `[sent for sent in sentences if 'not' not in sent]` will be much faster.

Comment: You might be right. My plan is to only **count** how many sentences contain `test` (but not `not`, to exclude negated sentences). I actually don't even need to know what exactly is the content of sentence